# Export map window as image

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have overlapping raster images in my QGIS map window. They had black corners due to previous warping. I put 0 (for black) into transparency. This all looks fine now.

When I do *Raster Tools > 'Convert map to raster'* the black corners come back. [EDIT: 'Convert map to raster' means **I want one output image of what I see in the whole map window**].

I also tried *Project > Export map to image*, but I can't keep the extent fixed while setting how many pixels I need.
QGIS 3.18.2

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: How do I get one seamless image? I don't want triangles of black from each overlapping image.

Comment: So, now there's overlap which wasn't mentioned before. I think you need to add an image to your question.

Comment: I don't have the image available. It is easy to imagine though. When a rectangular image is warped, this adds 'null' corners. In my case these are black. I can set them to show the black as transparent. If I do this to all overlapping images, I see *no* black. I now want to create one mosaic image that looks the same as what I now see.

Comment: You never mentioned the mosaic before, therefore one was led to think this is a single-image issue. Please update your question accordingly.